# Is the following statement, which an exercises in a textbook requires me to prove, false, or am I making a mistake?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I found the following exercises in a real analysis problem book:

Let $f:(0,+\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an arbitrary function satisfying the following hypotheses:

1. $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x(f(x)-1)=0$
2. $f(1)=2$
3. $(x+2)f(x+2)-2(x+1)f(x+1)+xf(x)=0 \space  \forall x>0 $

Prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=\infty$.

Now, it seems to me that there is a function which satisfies the hypothesis but not the thesis.

Consider $a(x)=x-1 $ if $x\in \mathbb{N}$, $a(x)=\lfloor x \rfloor$ otherwise; and $g(x)=xf(x)=2x-a(x)$.

The function $f$ satisfies condition 1, because, for $x<1$, $a(x)=0$ and thus $x(f(x)-1)=2x-x=x$.
Condition 2 is also satisfied since $f(1)=g(1)/1=g(1)=2$.
For the third condition, noting that $g(x+1)-g(x)=1$ sufficies to prove it holds.

But clearly the limit of $f(x)=2-a(x)/x$ as $x\rightarrow 0$ is $2$, since, again, for $x<1$ $a(x)=0$.

Where is my mistake?

(Also, please don't answer by solving the problem, as I'd like to do it myself)

Comment: Why does the function $a$ satisfy $\;\;\; x\cdot \hspace{.04 in}f(x) \: = \: (2\cdot x)-a(x) \;\;\;$? $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer: He defines $f$ by that relation, no?

Comment: I defined $g$ as $g(x)=2x-a(x)$, and then $xf(x)$ as $f(x)=g(x)/x$

Comment: does the exercise assumes that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: I checked all your conclusions, they are all correct. So unless there is additional information, the exercise is not correct. A continuity condition seems like a natural assumption.

Comment: I reported the text verbatim, so no assumption of continuity (also, the concept of continuity is introduced only later in the book)

Comment: I agree with @Mathematician42 , you found a counterexample. The exercise is incorrect.